# geom_text position and paste %

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Here is my dataframe `despesa_anys_ESP_decilsllar`:

```
structure(list(Any = c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020"), decils_renda = c("1r", 
"2n", "3r", "4t", "5è", "6è", "7è", "8è", "9è", "10è", 
"1r", "2n", "3r", "4t", "5è", "6è", "7è", "8è", "9è", "10è"
), despesatotal = c(13866.4, 18324.6, 21495.5, 24455.3, 28460.8, 
29818, 33897, 37897.3, 43373.1, 57458.4, 13280.3, 17337.7, 20666.9, 
22900.4, 25972.2, 27152.6, 30469.6, 32036.5, 37087.2, 49570.1
), despesamonetaria = c(9493.2, 13622.9, 16488.8, 19245.1, 22622.4, 
23780.2, 27213.5, 30793.5, 35457.3, 46773.7, 9006.1, 12629.2, 
15337.3, 17209.8, 19882.8, 20736.3, 23711.3, 24780.6, 28962.6, 
38315.8), proporcio_despesatotal = c(45.9, 60.6, 71.1, 80.9, 
94.1, 98.6, 112.1, 125.3, 143.4, 190, 49.2, 64.2, 76.6, 84.8, 
96.2, 100.6, 112.9, 118.7, 137.4, 183.6), proporcio_despesamonetaria = c(39.6, 
56.8, 68.8, 80.3, 94.4, 99.2, 113.5, 128.4, 147.9, 195.1, 43.9, 
61.5, 74.7, 83.9, 96.9, 101, 115.5, 120.8, 141.1, 186.7), despesatotal_gr = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -4.2, -5.4, -3.9, -6.4, -8.7, 
-8.9, -10.1, -15.5, -14.5, -13.7), despesamonetaria_gr = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -5.1, -7.3, -7, -10.6, -12.1, 
-12.8, -12.9, -19.5, -18.3, -18.1)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I want to add to my plot `geom_text`, being the label `despesamonetaria_gr` (for all `Anys` values, except `2019`, plus adding `%` to the label.

So far I did:

```
plot_despesa_decils_ESP <- ggplot(despesa_anys_ESP_decilsllar, aes(x = decils_renda, y = despesamonetaria, fill = Any)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width=0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous("", labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE), limits=c(0, 50000), breaks=seq(from=0, to=50000, by=5000),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(ifelse(!Any == "2019", despesamonetaria_gr, ""), "%"), family = "serif", size=6.5, hjust = -1.5, vjust = -2),
             show.legend = FALSE)
```

But the labels are not positioned correctly to their corresponding year:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule when adding labels to bars you have to account for the `position` in `geom_text` too, i.e. add `position = position_dodge(width = .9)` so that the labels are dodged in line with the bars. For the issue with the `%` I simply switched to `scales::percent`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(despesa_anys_ESP_decilsllar, aes(x = decils_renda, y = despesamonetaria, fill = Any)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", width = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous("",
    labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE),
    limits = c(0, 50000), breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 50000, by = 5000),
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0))
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = ifelse(!Any == "2019", scales::percent(despesamonetaria_gr, scale = 1), "")
    ),
    position = position_dodge(width = .9),
    family = "serif", size = 3, vjust = -.2,
    show.legend = FALSE
  )
```

[image]